# How to know what version of PHP is used on my xampp?

Tags: php, versions, xampp

I am using *xampp* on my *Ubuntu* OS. And I need to know what version of *PHP* my *xampp* is using.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Put this in your root directory:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Save it as `phpinfo.php` and point your browser to it (this could be http://localhost/phpinfo.php)

- [More information](http://php.net/phpinfo) (you can get much more information than just the version).
- Example (random image):

[image: Screenshot of phpinfo() output]

Comment: Hopefully `short_open_tag` is enabled, maybe `<?php`

Comment: the command is more good than creating this file.

Answer (score 7):

Try with command from terminal

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/php -v
```

Answer (score 5):

first you have to need the version of your Xampp

```
xampp -v
```

or

```
xampp --version
```

Then you can check the php version from [xampp website](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)

you can't know it from command line since it's bundled inside the Xampp

Comment: -v is better option

Comment: Ok friend I'll memorize that

Comment: or search this file readme_en.txt to find version details